# Power BI - Drop down selection

Tags: powerbi-desktop

We have used slicer in Power BI reports for Filtering purpose. In the slicer we have given the value field and make it as drop down. Also, we have enabled the multi-select option. Now if we expand the drop down all items are displayed with checkboxes for multi-select purpose.

But if select multiple items in the drop down the selection is not clear. We need to enable the tick mark in the checkbox while selecting the item. How to enable the tick mark in checkbox while selecting the item in the Slicer drop down. Kindly help us on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that in Slicer Setting , Multi-Select with CTRL option is turned off.

When it is turned off, you will notice the tick mark in the items when selecting the item.

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if I turned off the Multi-Select with CTRL option i can see the tick mark. thank you very much.